# insatll php-fpm patch for php5.2.x

Tags: php

I have php 5.2.17 and i download relevent php-fpmm file "php-5.2.17-fpm-0.5.14.diff.gz "
form php-fpm.rg But I don't know how to install this patch 
i use slackware 13.1 x64

Answer (score 3):

untar you php and the patch and then configure php to use it

```
tar -xvzf php-5.2.17.tar.gz
tar -xvzf php-5.2.17-fpm-0.5.14.diff.gz
cd php-5.2.17
patch -p1 < php-5.2.17-fpm-0.5.14.diff
./configure --enable-fpm <and your other options you want>
```